# IGBT trailing edge dimmer: the LED bulb only lights up around 40%, strange wave form before that, please advise what is causing that

Tags: led, igbt, dimmer

I built a trailing edge dimmer with IGBT, and I am driving it using Raspberry Pi 3.
The circuit mostly works, but I noticed some strange behavior, that I can't put my finger on.
Please could you help me understand what is causing these, and how could I fix them?

### Issue #1:

The first issue can be noticed when I start dimming the light gradually without turning the bulb on beforehand.

If I am turning the light ON for 1 second, and then I am gradually increasing dimming ratio from 0% to 100% in 20 seconds, then dimming works nicely, and the signal looks good
(Oscilloscope recording can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vlOzIwuK63a_EePXE0lIbEr8_EyxDA_K/view?usp=sharing)).
[image]

However if I do not turn the light ON at the beginning, just start dimming, then the bulb remains off in the first 8 seconds, and the signal looks distorted in this period. After 8 seconds the light finally turns ON, and the signal looks good again
(Oscilloscope recording can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZS8NUHotQiPPx3hhpJt4BW-LdAa2wQfi/view?usp=sharing)).
[image]

Please could you help me understand why the signal is distorted, and why the bulb remains initially OFF?

### Issue #2:

A few seconds after turning the IGBT OFF I noticed a signal on the bulb.
This signal slowly decreases, and eventually "almost" disappears after a minute or so.
Please could you let me know where this signal is coming from?
(Oscilloscope recording can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XqYDYcV8xNZMCVs3rOORQBjFwapo1Dk1/view?usp=sharing))
[image]

### Circuit:

[image][image]

Please could you give me any pointer?

(My zero-cross detector fires early, that can be noticed on the pictures. I will fix that later in software. I believe this has nothing to do with the issues.)

Comment: Where are you probing with the scope? How are you isolating the scope if probing across the lamp?

Comment: I directly connected the probes to J4 and J5 without any isolation. The scope is a PicoScope 2000.

Comment: Where are your schematics of the load circuit?  What do you mean by LED "bulb"?  Does it have its own circuitry?  If so, the reason for your difference in function could be that it takes time for the LED driver circuitry to charge up it's drive voltage.  If you start at 100% power it's virtually instant and dimming works properly after that.  If you start at 1% power it takes time to get the circuit charged to the voltage it can work efficiently at, and some bulbs will even flicker indefinitely until you turn them up to a minimum power level that lets them charge to an efficient condition.

Comment: Also if it is a "bulb", is it dimmable and is it from a reputable manufacturer?  The bulk of lights I've seen that had this problem were from el cheapo manufacturers or older lights not intended for dimming mismatched to a newer driver.

Comment: The better quality led lightbulbs have a bridge rectifier, filter capacitor and a constant current buck converter. If the bulb is not dimmable, the buck converter will start snd stop and get generally upset. The dimmable ones are designed to accept phase control dimming although the low end of the dimming range is generally not good. Considering you can get wifi bulbs that do pwm dimmibg, why are you bothering with phase control?

Comment: Thanks all for the good questions, and great advises. I use dimmable E26 light bulbs, so they all must have their own circuitry. I could not tell if they are from "reputable manufacturer", but I noticed similar behavior from 2 different brands. Do you see anything in my circuit that could cause these issues? Or is it certainly the bulb circuitry?

Comment: Regarding the WiFi PWM bulbs: I have an existing home setup with many bulbs that I would like to drive.